# What is thermistor Beta?

Tags: thermistor

In the attached [datasheet](https://www.littelfuse.com/%7E/media/electronics/datasheets/leaded_thermistors/littelfuse_leaded_thermistors_interchangeable_thermistors_standard_precision_ps_datasheet.pdf.pdf), I see the Beta value (K) is from 0degC to +50degC.

What does it actually signify in terms of usage in an application?

Like, how to understand that parameter if I have to consider its value in my design (for calculation)

There's a separate column that mentions the temperature rating. What the difference between these 2 columns?

Can someone please explain?

Comment: Is it an NTC thermistor?

Comment: Yes it is @Andyaka

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *What does it actually signify in terms of usage in an application?*

For an NTC thermistor, this is how the relationship is formed around β: -

$$\Large R_T = R_{25}\cdot e^{\beta\left(\frac{1}{T}-\frac{1}{298.15}\right)}$$

The bits of the above equation are: -

- \$R_T\$ is the actual value of the thermistor at some temperature (\$T\$)
- \$R_{25}\$ is the value thermistor resistance at 25 °C. This is given in the data sheet: -

[image]

- \$e\$ is a mathematical constant (as per natural exponentials)
- \$\beta\$ is given in the data sheet
- \$T\$ is the temperature of the thermistor
- \$298.15\$ is the kelvin temperature at 25 °C aka \$T_{25}\$.

So, if you know \$R\$ you can rearrange the formula to find \$T\$.

> *There's a separate column that mentions the temperature rating*

This is the range of temperatures that the thermistor can be used to make temperature measurements. However, the value of β given in the data sheet is only accurate between 0 °C and +50 °C. Outside this range the formula becomes a tad more complex due to non-linearities.

[This site](https://www.giangrandi.org/electronics/ntc/ntc.shtml) has some good explanations also (and a calculator).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But could you tell me What does it actually signify in terms of usage in an application?

Comment: Usage in an application is purely mathematical: you measure the thermistor resistance and infer the temperature  using an arrangement of the formula in my answer. In other words, it's how R changes with temperature.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. Let me understand and come back to accept this answer.

Comment: @Newbie I think you may need to follow up on this.

Answer (score 3):

I searched "thermistor beta" (https://www.google.com/search?q=thermistor+beta) and got this result (https://www.ametherm.com/thermistor/ntc-thermistor-beta):

"A thermistor’s “b” value, or beta value, is an indication of the shape of the curve representing the relationship between resistance and temperature of an NTC thermistor. "

> What does it actually signify in terms of usage in an application?

If you have a product that expects a particular thermistor, and you want to replace it with another thermistor, you would need to match both the resistance at room temperature (e.g., 10 kΩ) and the beta in the specified temperature range. Note that various thermistor specify different temperature ranges, some specify more than one range.

On the other hand, if you're designing your own device, then you don't care about beta, you only care about the table with resistance vs temperature.

> What the difference between these 2 columns?

The first column is temperature, the second column is nominal resistance at that temperature.

Comment: So, the beta is not related to the operating temperature of the device, right?

Comment: Yes, I was not able to understand that definition. What is the meaning of, " is an indication of the shape of the curve" - Indication of the shape of the curve?

Comment: _the beta is not related to the operating temperature of the device_ Correct. It's a fixed characteristic of the thermistor, regardless of the temperature it happens to be. By analogy, the "beta" of a bowl is an indication of its shape, and the shape of a bowl is constant, regardless of how much water is in it.

Comment: _ Indication of the shape of the curve?_ That's as well as it can be said is words. Beyod that, words fail and you must resort to math. For a precise definition of how beta describes that curve, see the mathematical equation in the page I linked.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. So in simple terms, in this datasheet, why should I be worried about the Beta and when/at which situation should I care about Beta?

Comment: @Newbie whenever you want to get correct temperature readings.

Comment: As I said: "If you have a product that expects a particular thermistor, and you want to replace it with another thermistor, you would need to match both the resistance at room temperature (e.g., 10 kΩ) and the beta in the specified temperature range."

Answer (score 2):

A simple search for "thermistor beta" will give you the equation that derives beta from the resistance of the thermistor at two different temperatures (R1 and R2 at T2 and T2 respectively). In the data sheet you are given beta and the resistance at 25 °C so you can get the temperature, given the measured resistance, by reversing the calculation. **NOTE** the temperature in the equation is in Kelvin, **NOT** Centigrade.

The "Temperature Rating" is the maximum and minimum temperatures to which the thermistor may be subject without it suffering any permanent degradation. The "Storage & Operational Temp for best Long Term Stability" are just that. The manufacturers are saying that the device will work best if used and stored between these two temperatures.